# JavaScript converting an object to an array

Tags: javascript

I've researched for about a day and haven't had any luck. I'm trying to access the object properties to simply add it to a typed class in JavaScript. How can i accomplish this? This is the object im receiving:

[image]

And this my code resulting in the following error:

```
Object.keys(selected).forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(selected[key]);
    });
```

Error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Any help is most appreciated as I've come to here as a last resort.

selected looks like this:
[image]

Object.keys(selected)... the selected in json string:

```
{
 "selected": [
    {
      "Id": 4,
      "Type": 0,
      "Image": "",
      "Name": "TestName",
      "Roles": "TestRole",
      "Facility": "TestFacil"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `selected.selected` exists. Try `selected[0]` and see if it works. You might also have to change the log line to ouput `selected[0][key]`.

Comment: Just tried, same result @CoreyOgburn

Comment: Maybe I'm not recreating your situation properly then. Here's a jsfiddle of my attempt to do so: https://jsfiddle.net/rct8y82L/

Comment: please stringify the object and post it here instead of showing us pictures

Comment: updated question with 'selected' stringified. @Kristianmitk

Comment: @tshoemake this question is about neither angular nor or typescript please don't spam tags

Comment: Ok, i just added cause it's within an angular component and using typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable selected is an array, you can try this:

```
selected.forEach(
  item=>
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key) {
      console.log(item[key]);
    })
)
```

It could also be:

```
selected.selected.forEach(
```

In your question it's not clear what the name is of the value you are logging the json string of.

Comment: This did it.  It was selected.selected.forEach that worked for me.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
 "selected": [
    {
      "Id": 4,
      "Type": 0,
      "Image": "",
      "Name": "TestName",
      "Roles": "TestRole",
      "Facility": "TestFacil"
    }
  ]
}


let arr = [];
for (var key in data) {
  arr.push(data[key]);
}

console.log(arr)
```

or you can use that if you wanna convert the whole object to `arrays` of `arrays`

```js
        let data = {
         "selected": [
            {
              "Id": 4,
              "Type": 0,
              "Image": "",
              "Name": "TestName",
              "Roles": "TestRole",
              "Facility": "TestFacil"
            }
          ]
        }


    var arr = [];
    var i =0;
    for( var key in data){
      var innerArr = [key];
      arr.push(innerArr)
      for(var values in data[key]){
       for(var keys in data[key][values]){
         var innerArr3 = [keys];
         innerArr.push(innerArr3)
         innerArr3.push(data[key][values][keys])
        }
      }
    }
     console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This gives me the following error.. TypeError: selected.forEach is not a function

Comment: @tshoemake, i have added 2 options ,so to make the outer object as an array or to dig in the whole objects to arrays